# How to add a "depends" condition on valueNotEquals rule in jQuery Validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use the "depend" in jQuery Validation plugin in order to apply some validation rules only in specific cases. This is the code I use to do it in case I want a field `required` only under certain circumstances.

```
 fieldA: {
required: {depends: function () {
        return $('#FormName select[name="fieldB"]').val() === '10';
    }}
 }
```

In case I want to use the `valueNotEquals` rule I have a syntax like this:

```
fieldA:
 {valueNotEquals: "0"}
```

If I want to use "depends", what is the right syntax? These two attempts gave error and syntax error.

**Attemp 1** (error for I could not indicate WHAT value it must not equals)

```
fieldA:
     {valueNotEquals: {depends: function () {
         return $('#QuestionarioForm select[name="lavoroMadre"]').val() === '10';}}
```

**Attemp 2** (syntax error)

```
fieldA:
     {valueNotEquals: "0" {depends: function () {
         return $('#QuestionarioForm select[name="lavoroMadre"]').val() === '10';}}
```

Comment: Show the _rendered_ HTML markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
fieldA:
 {valueNotEquals: "0"}
```

**Quote Title**:

> *"How to add a “depends” condition on valueNotEquals rule in jQuery Validation plugin?"*

Your code is not working because **there is no such rule or method called `valueNotEquals`** in the jQuery Validate plugin.

**Documented rules & methods**:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/

---

You'll have to write your own custom rule using [`addMethod()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || (value != params[0]);
}, "Please specify a value that is not equal to {0}");
```

And declare the rule:

```
fieldA: {
    valueNotEquals: [0]
}
```

**DEMO of custom method**:  http://jsfiddle.net/cF3p5/

---

Now you wouldn't need to use `depends`.  Simply edit this custom function so that it behaves as you want.  Maybe something more like this...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, params) {
    if ($('#QuestionarioForm select[name="lavoroMadre"]').val() === params[1]) {
        return (value != params[0]);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "Please specify a value that is not equal to {0}");
```

And declare the rule:

```
fieldA: {
    valueNotEquals: [0, 10]
}
```

Comment: Power of copy/paste on code made a lot of time ago. I have totally forgot that self made function. Your custom method works perfectly! Thanks a lot!